# Autocmd-buflocal response to wrong buffer

Tags: vim, buffer, local, autocmd

I use vim open a file, and the buffer id(`bufnr()`) is `2`, then I run a function `PreviewJupyterMD` in Vim commandline by `call PreviewJupyterMD()`.

The function body is like:

```
function! PreviewJupyterMD()
    " creat a md file and load file name to a variable l:md_file
    ...
    ...
    exec "edit" . l:md_file
    let b:created_for_jupyter = 1
    autocmd BufUnload <buffer> call MDCleanUp()
endfunction
```

So what I do is use `edit` open a new file and load it to buffer 3(I checked it by `bufnr()`, too). And add a local variable to buffer 3. Then I want vim run `MDCleanUp` function for buffer 3 when I close Vim.

What `MDCleanUp` do is check whether buffer has a variable if so delete file of that buffer from disk:

```
function! MDCleanUp()
    if exists("b:created_for_jupyter")
        call delete(expand("<afile>:p"))
    endif
    " below 2 line use to know this function run on which buffer
    echom bufnr()
    sleep 4
endfunction
```

---

The actural behavior is `MDCleanUp` run twice, but all output message by `echom bufnr()` is 2, output 2 twice!

Would you give me some instruction or suggestion about why the output is:

```
2
2
```

and how to let it be:

```
2
3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read `:h BufUnload`? (hint: after the word "NOTE").

Comment: @Matt Yeah, it not about `<afile>:p`, `%` get same result. If you mean not change buffer, I do it this way as I saw an example. That plugin use `edit` open a filen, then do some operation to the new buffer. And finally delete it successfully. https://github.com/gabenespoli/vim-jupycent/blob/59f5ce852c23f1db0b7deba7e4fc6876dabe57d4/plugin/jupycent.vim#L46